# Omitting the info above the headers from the output of linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to execute the command

kubectl exec -it <container_name> -n kube-system -- /bin/df -P

the above is giving some output as below:

[image]

I want to remove the Defaulted container "fluentd" and so on... I want to remove that line from output

I tried with that command | sed -n '1!p' This command is not helping us to remove that line. It is removing the next line file system 1024 blocks that one

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Copy&paste the command and its output *as text* to your question, both the output shown in the image and the output of the pipe with the `sed` command.

Answer (score 2):

The unwanted output is going to standard error; you can discard it with

```
kubectl … 2>/dev/null
```

but that would get rid of any other errors too.

I haven’t checked but the `-q` option might get rid of the output too:

```
kubectl exec -q -it …
```

Comment: Thanks stephen kitt

Comment: @user535929 If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.